# How to find every matches using look ahead in python regex?

Tags: python, regex-lookarounds

I am looking for a pattern to find the matches below:

```
match BLA match match BLA match BLA text
```

I tried this one:pattern = `([\w]*)(?=BLA)`, and got the return:
match BLA match match BLA match

the desired result is:

match, match match, match.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your desired output?

Comment: so you want every word that has a BLA somewhere later in the string? But those first two BLA are words with a BLA somewhere later in the string.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the matches except BLA when there is BLA at the right:

```
\b(?!BLA\b)\w+(?=.*\bBLA\b)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?!BLA\b)` Negative lookahead, assert not BLA directly to the right of the current position
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?=.*\bBLA\b)` Positive lookahead, assert BLA at the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S6omZY/1)